# Global variable assigned in useEffect cannot be used in other function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, use-state

I have the following code which sends some data to my firebase database upon clicking a button. However, whenever I click it I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined`. The weird thing is that if I post without writing any content it works fine. My code is below:

```
// import statements

function ComponentName(props) {
// declare and assign useStates

var db;
    useEffect(() => {
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp({firebaseConfig});
        setFirebaseInitialized(true);
        db = firebase.firestore();
    }, []);


    function sendPostToFirebase() {
        db.collection("blogPosts").add({ // These three variables below are states
            author: blogPostAuthor,
            title: blogPostTitle,
            content: blogPostContent,
            datePublished: Date.now(),
            dateLastEdited: Date.now()
        })
            .then(function (docRef) {
                console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
                alert("Successfully posted!");

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
                alert("ERROR: " + error);
            });
    };

    // return HTML stuff
}
```

It seems that the problem is that the db variable is not being updated in the useEffect hook.

I have made sure to declare db as a global variable. I suspect the reason why it's not working has to do with the assignment inside useEffect, but I'm not sure if that is so, or how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why the downvote? I have provided the necessary information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue myself by getting rid of the useEffect and making a separate js file for firebaseDB initialization things. Here it is:

firebaseDB.js:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore';

const config = {
// put your config here

};

export default !firebase.apps.length
    ? firebase.initializeApp(config).firestore()
    : firebase.app().firestore();
```

In BlogEditorComponent.jsx:

`import db from "./firebaseDB`

and treat db normally.